# HP-UX network traffic

Tags: network-monitoring, network-traffic, hp-ux

Does HP-UX (11.31) has a command in order to check the current traffic (**in bps**) going through it's network card?

`Netstat -i` only gives the I/O in terms of packets. We don't have a glance license, so I'm looking for a "default"/standard solution.

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably be tempted to look at downloading the source for [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/download.html), and compile it for HP-UX.  There's also [ntop](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=425526), which may or may not be available as binaries, but is definitely available as source.

Apparently [Cricket](http://cricket.sourceforge.net/) will also do what you want.  I suspect you can compile munin-node to do the same, also. Or use snmpd and munin.